# Meteor: Count data from collection

Tags: meteor

anyone please i need you help. before this I have asking question but I cannit find this solution. I have create code to count variable in collection. I can get the result when count one by one but not by group. Thats my code, I want to count this but the code not given any resut to me. I want the result like this:

> PTR 1
>   KOM 4

```
This my code:
<template name="laporankategori"> 
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Jenis Peralatan</th>
        <th>Kuantiti</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each profil}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{PTR}}</td>
          <td>{{KOM}}</td>  
        </tr>   
      {{/each}} 
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

//js

```
Template.laporankategori.helpers({
  profil: function() {
    return Profil.find({kategori: { $in: ['PTR', 'KOM'] } }).count();
  }
});
```

Comment: Where are your `PTR` and `KOM` helpers / context variables?

Comment: means? because i already use this code like `profil: function() {
return Profil.find({kategori:'PTR' }).count(); 
}` and it's working. Now I try for this code `profil: function() {
return Profil.find({kategori: { $in: ['PTR', 'KOM'] } }).count();
}` and its not working. I not sure where is problem accuatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template name="laporankategori"> 
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Jenis Peralatan</th>
     <th>Kuantiti</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   {{#each profil}}
     <tr>
       <td>{{count}}</td>
     </tr>
   {{/each}} 
  </tbody>
 </table>
</template>
```

//js

```
Template.laporankategori.helpers({
 profil: function() {
  var PTR = { 
    count: Profil.find({kategori: { $in: ['PTR'] } }).count()
  };
  var KOM = { 
    count : Profil.find({kategori: { $in: ['KOM'] } }).count()
  };
  var resultArr = [PTR, KOM];
  return resultArr;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're iterating with `{{#each ...}}` your helper should return either a cursor or an array. Your helper is returning a scalar: the count. In your `{{#each }}` block you refer to `{{PTR}}` and `{{KOM}}` but those won't exist.

I suspect that you weren't actually looking for the count in this case and your helper should just be:

```
Template.laporankategori.helpers({
  profil: function() {
    return Profil.find({kategori: { $in: ['PTR', 'KOM'] } });
  }
});
```

Also you don't often need to count things in a helper since in a template you can refer to `{{profil.count}}` and get the count of the cursor directly.

Comment: Can guide me how to use `group aggregate count`